# Ruby Threads output

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I am reading David A. Black's The Well-Grounded Rubyist, 3rd Edition.

In the section on threads, the author's output of the following code snippet differs from what appears on my system (section 14.5).

```
Thread.new do
  puts "Starting the thread"
  sleep 1
  puts "At the end of the thread"
end
puts "Outside the thread"
```

Author's output:

```
Starting the thread
Outside the thread
```

My output is only:

```
Outside the thread
```

The author then sets the code block to variable `t` and calls `t.join` which gives him the following output:

```
Starting the thread
Outside the thread
At the end of the thread
```

However, my output is:

```
Outside the thread
Starting the thread
At the end of the thread
```

Am I missing something?

I am using ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Comment: I recommend reading the docs for `Thread`, specifically https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Thread.html#method-i-join.  As @Pan Ke points out, there's no `join` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Because main thread continue doing the job before the spawned thread starts.

1, try to put a sleep 0.1 before `puts "Outside the thread"`

```rb
Thread.new do
  puts "Starting the thread"
  sleep 1
  puts "At the end of the thread"
end
sleep 0.1 #let spawned thread start
puts "Outside the thread"
```

2. join before `puts "Outside the thread"`

```rb
Thread.new do
  puts "Starting the thread"
  sleep 1
  puts "At the end of the thread"
end.join # wait spawned thread finish
puts "Outside the thread"
```